# Is "kill" a valid translation for Exodus 20:13 (Thou shalt not kill)?

Tags: hebrew, exodus, ten-commandments

> [Exodus 20:13 (KJV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2020:13&version=KJV)
> Thou shalt not kill.

Many political statements have been made about this verse.  This translation has been used by many to support their pacifist desires.  However, it seems that most translations have dropped "kill" in favor of "murder".

> [Exodus 20:13 (NKJV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2020:13&version=NKJV)
> You shall not murder.

Is "kill" a valid translation of this word?  Why have translations stopped using the word "kill" in favor of "murder"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The lexicons referenced in Blundin's answer are trying to define the word *ratsach* throughout the whole of the OT. The differences between these different dictionaries and lexicons imply that the word doesn't have a single unambiguous translation but that it can mean different things in different contexts.

The OP asked what the word ratsach means in Exodus 20:13. In [Deuteronomy 35:6-33](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2035&version=NIV) the word means “to kill unintentionally,” however unintentional killing is probably not forbidden in the Ten Commandments. So, from within the context of the Ten Commandments, the word *ratsach* almost definitely means "murder."

Comment: Totally agreed.  So, while "kill" could be a valid translation, "murder" is a better one since it's a "Thou Shalt Not".  It doesn't make much sense to say You shall not have an accident.

Comment: @Richard I agree with the logic of your statement on the command nature of the phrase.

Comment: @blundin, we're in agreement. The word is ambiguous and using Richard's logic we rule out one of its possible meanings suggesting that in the context of 20:13 it most likely means "murder."

Comment: Along with that, it would be difficult to reason that one of God's foundational rules was "do not kill" in a general sense, when numerous other passages discuss doing exactly that for various reasons.

Comment: The distinction between unintentional and intentional killing is important, but it's far from the only meaningful distinction to be made. There are many types of intentional killing that are not considered murder. Are these being forbidden by the Ten Commandments? For one, is the forbidden intentional killing limited to killing of humans? Further, does it only forbid murder, or also capital punishment, or war?  These are the questions that most people struggle with--not whether it's a sin to accidentally kill someone.

Comment: @Flimzy, [PETA has recently suggested](http://www.seattlepi.com/news/article/PETA-lawsuit-seeks-to-expand-animal-rights-2235777.php) that the 13th amendment of the US Constitution be applied to enslavement of animals in addition to humans. This reading of the constitution is absurd and sure to be laughed out of court. The verse is Exodus 21:13 is definitely addressing the killing human beings. Capital punishment and war plays a central role in many a Biblical narrative so it definitely doesn't include those either.

Comment: (I absolutely do not endorse the enslavement of animals)

Comment: @Amichai: Valid points.  I think they would make a good addition to your answer. :)

Comment: How do we know that ratsach  means murder in ten commandment but means unintentional killing in Deuteronomy 35:6-33 ? Maybe Deuteronomy 35:6-33 is reserved for murderers too. But why would God give refugees for murderers?

Comment: should this be it's own question?

Comment: @Amichai, This answer is *invalid*/incorrect: **(A.)** Specifically, this is an inductive argument masquerading as a deductive one, it is also "begging the question";  **(B.)** Specifically, you state "it means unintentional killing", "because the 10 commandments **probably** doesn't forbid unintentional killing", therefore it **certainly** means "unintentional killing, (that is circular and begging the question). **(D.)**  Unintentional killing is also unlawful, if neglect; **(E.)** Your answer is also not substantiated by any source that would substantiate your claim.

Answer (score 14):

In the Jewish understanding, every negative commandment of the Torah (the Five Books of Moses, i.e. Genesis through Deuteronomy) consists of two parts, a notice of what a violation would encompass, and a second mention to indicate the punishment.  If you have additional references to a command, they must be teaching something else.  See Introduction to Sifra.  Similarly, when we look at the commandments of the Decalogue, we study them as a unit because each of the 10 statements (not all are commands) were given to us directly by G-d, and therefore must be of special importance.

Two of the ten commandments are difficult to understand in this context, unless they mean something somewhat different: these are "do not steal" and "do not kill."  If we understand these literally, the first is redundant -- the Torah has elsewhere told us of the offense of stealing and of the punishment for theft (Lev. 19:13; Ex. 21:37-22:3); and the second is vague -- the Torah at times commands us to kill (e.g. Deut. 25:17-19) and exempts those persons who are killed accidentally (Num. 35:22).  Yet, for the case of intentional murder, there is a punishment described -- death (Ex. 21:12-14), but no separate verse making it a crime.

We see that, other than these two commandments in question, the other commandments of the Decalogue share one aspect -- they describe capital crimes.  Idolatry and blasphemy, extreme cases of dishonor to parents, adultery, false testimony in a capital case, and violating the sabbath day all were capital crimes.  Kidnapping and murder are described as capital crimes in Ex. 21, but although the punishment is described, there are no verses warning of the offense.  The rabbis, therefore, determined that the Decalogue commandment of "lo tignov" applied to the stealing of a person, and "lo tirtzach" meant "do not murder," and not just "do not kill" (See [Rashi to Ex. 20:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/showrashi/false/aid/9881/jewish/Chapter-20.htm), citing Babyl. Talmud Sanhedrin 86a).

Comment: Yes the "Laws of the Breath" (The Ten Commandments) are contrary to the "Punishment Laws of the Flesh" (Given through Moses)

Answer (score 11):

Given what the various dictionaries define I think "murder" is the more appropriate word, although there is some debate. So you can see for yourself I have posted some citations below.

From the Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains:

> 8357 רָצַח (rā∙ṣǎḥ): v.; ≡ Str 7523; TWOT 2208—LN 20.61–20.88 (qal)
>   murder, kill, i.e., take the life one another so as to cause a state
>   of death (Ex 20:13; Nu 35:6, 11, 12, 16,17,18,19, 21,25, 26, 27,28,
>   30,31; Dt 4:42; 5:17; 19:3, 4, 6; 22:26; Jos 20:3, 5, 6; 21:13, 21,
>   27, 32, 38; 1Ki 21:19; Job 24:14; Jer 7:9; Hos 4:2+), note: this
>   action can refer to an accident, manslaughter, premeditation, or
>   governmental execution; (nif) murdered, be killed (Jdg 20:4; Pr
>   22:13+); (piel) murder, kill (Ps 62:4[EB 3]; 94:6; Hos 6:9+), note:
>   for piel ptcp. as a noun in 2Ki 6:32; Isa 1:21, see 5344.5

From Strong's Enhanced Lexicon:

> 7523 רָצַח [ratsach /raw·tsakh/] v. A primitive root; TWOT 2208; GK
>   8357; 47 occurrences; AV translates as “slayer” 16 times, “murderer”
>   14 times, “kill” five times, “murder” three times, “slain” three
>   times, “manslayer” twice, “killing” once, “slayer + 310” once,
>   “slayeth” once, and “death” once. 1 to murder, slay, kill. 1A (Qal) to
>   murder, slay. 1A1 premeditated. 1A2 accidental. 1A3 as avenger. 1A4
>   slayer (intentional) (participle). 1B (Niphal) to be slain. 1C (Piel).
>   1C1 to murder, assassinate. 1C2 murderer, assassin
>   (participle)(subst). 1D (Pual) to be killed.

From The Abridged Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew-English Lexicon of the Old Testament:

> vb. murder, slay — Qal murder, slay, with premeditation; c. acc.
>   pers., unawares; slay as avenger; esp. pt. as subst. = slayer,
>   manslayer, without intent; murderer, with intent. Niph. be slain;
>   murdered. Pi. (intens.) murder, assassinate; Pt. as subst. murderer,
>   assassin. Pu.

---

*Swanson, J. (1997). Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains : Hebrew (Old Testament) (electronic ed.). Oak Harbor: Logos Research Systems, Inc.*

*Whitaker, R., Brown, F., Driver, S. (. R., & Briggs, C. A. (. A. (1997). The Abridged Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew-English Lexicon of the Old Testament : From A Hebrew and English Lexicon of the Old Testament by Francis Brown, S.R. Driver and Charles Briggs, based on the lexicon of Wilhelm Gesenius. Oak Harbor WA: Logos Research Systems, Inc.*

*Strong, J. (1996). The exhaustive concordance of the Bible : Showing every word of the text of the common English version of the canonical books, and every occurrence of each word in regular order. (electronic ed.). Ontario: Woodside Bible Fellowship.*

Answer (score -1):

Everyone looks at "kill" vs "murder" but misses the critical "thou" at the beginning of the verse. It is not your right as an individual to decide to cause death. We must take care that we do not cause death accidentally or intentionally. Capital punishment or war are decided by the "men at the gate of the city" or government or by G-d. So, I believe the term should be translated with the broadest possible meaning, which is "kill".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Umm.... ok.  So, what if I were a judge and I had to decide on capital punishment?  What if I were a general and I had to send men to war?  What if I wake up to find someone in my house with a weapon, should I grab my gun in response?  REGARDLESS, this is just passing the buck and not answering the question.  The question is about translation...

Answer (score -1):

“לא תרצח ס”

“Not she/you slay [unknown word]” is the literal translation.

”לא” means “not”. “תרצח” has the prefix “ת” which means “she” or "you" (depending on context). The word “רצח” means “slay”. The word “ס” is unknown.

Its that simple.

There are certain times in the Bible when killing is permitted, and they are always for punishing someone for doing something wrong (such as killing).

Other than that, no killing.

“Eye for eye, tooth for tooth, hand for hand, foot for foot.” (Exodus 21).

Comment: While תִּרְצַח‎ can indicate a feminine-gender subject, it only does so in the 3rd person, which would be equivalent to the English: “she will not kill”. Since this is a prohibition, thus requiring the 2nd person, תִּרְצַח‎ is masculine-gender, 2nd person: “you (masculine, singular) shall not kill”.

Comment: “Two sets of forms (2ms/3fs), 2fp/3fp) are identical, and can be distinguished only by context” ([link](https://templeton.eastern.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/Reading-Understanding-Biblical-Hebrew-Part-2-by-Dr-Fred-Putnam.pdf))

Comment: I don’t trust your source, it doesn’t use Hebrew letters which takes away from the authenticity of the meaning.

Comment: The fact that you edited your post to reflect what both my source and I stated suggests otherwise.

Comment: Of course I did, I am bot ignorant. I simply don’t trust specifically that source. I have a World Wide Web to learn from, and I used it.