# What is the actual word used in "Thou shall not kill?"

Tags: hebrew, exodus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “kill” a valid translation for Exodus 20:13 (Thou shalt not kill)?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-kill-a-valid-translation-for-exodus-2013-thou-shalt-not-kill)

What word is used in the original Ten Commandments for "kill"? What modern equivalent best represents this words intended meaning? Did it mean just murder, or kill secretly, or illegal killing?

Comment: I think this is a pure Biblical Hermeneutics question, should probably be moved there

Comment: "What are the exact words?" And "What should we understand them to mean today?" Are two different questions. Which would you like to ask? Your current question is an awkward cross-breed that we can't exactly answer here, but if you pick a direction we can edit or get you to the right place.

Comment: The actual words are "לֹא תִּרְצָֽח׃ ס", apparently

Comment: Jim please comment on where you way to go with this or edit it into something, then we can reopen as an answerable question here or elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I can't read hebrew :). Oh it's duplicate. Yes it's a simple question.