# Is there a contradiction in the Bible related to death penalty?

Tags: john, exodus, law, torah, death

I'm curious with the fact that the sixth commandment says, that one can't kill the other, this is (**Exodus 20:13**):

> 13 “You shall not murder.

However, in the bible, there are many moments where this is permitted, as it seems to me, as in **Exodus 21:12, 22:19,Leviticus 20:10**. And it's in the New Testment (**Romans 6:23**):

> 23 For the wages of sin is death, but the free gift of God is eternal
> life in Christ Jesus our Lord.

I know that *death penalty* in some cases can be permitted in Torah and also others that can't, as Jesus was in **John 8:1-11** trying to balance the situation between those that want to stone a woman but they have also many sins. So the question is: how to judge correctly (which parameters) if a case deserves *death penalty* and those that don't?

*obs.: this question differs from others because I want to know if death penalty in the Torah can be applied under certain circumstances (which) and not just about being intentional or not murder.*

In addition, I'd also like some examples in the Torah where this is permitted and where this is not.

Comment: Murder is not equivalent to kill, and executions demanded by the law are obviously excluded.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-kill-a-valid-translation-for-exodus-2013-thou-shalt-not-kill

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "kill" a valid translation for Exodus 20:13 (Thou shalt not kill)?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-kill-a-valid-translation-for-exodus-2013-thou-shalt-not-kill)

Comment: Your last paragraph answers your own question : and then asks another question on that basis - 'So the question is _how to judge correctly_.' (Which may be off-topic.)

Comment: The question asks "which" circumstances, the aswers for the above questions don't say very well this aspect.

Comment: Are you asking how to apply the laws about the death penalty, or about a "contradiction" with Exodus 20:13? Those are two very different questions.

Comment: Romans 6:23 is entirely irrelevant.. it has absolutely nothing to do with the death penalty.  It is merely saying the consequence of sin is spiritual death, physical death, and the second death.

Comment: If you want to give a better answer, I suggest you give one.

Comment: Dottard's answer is good, as is Dave's. If you want a more complete answer then you could try "Evangelical Ethics - issues facing the church today" by John Jefferson Davis.

Answer (score 3):

In understanding this important legal principle, we must recall that the Hebrew verbs are quite different:

- In Ex 20:13 we have רָצַח (ratsach) is an illegal killing, ie, murder.
- In Ex 21:12, 22:19, Lev 20:10, we have מוּת (muth), ie, a killing of any description.

Note that the 6th commandment does NOT outlaw killing generally, else no army could go to war.  It simply outlaws illegal killing, ie, murder.

[NOTE:  The same is true in modern society where murder is illegal but killing more generally is possible where it is legally sanctioned, and only under state authority.]

Thus, the 6th commandment actually says, "*You shall not murder*", as per NIV, NLT, ESV, BSB, NKJV, NASB, CSB, HCSB, CEV, ERV, GNT, GWT, ISV, JPS, NET, WEB, etc.  [The KJV is not helpful here.]

The Amplified Bible correctly gives this:

> “You shall not commit murder (unjustified, deliberate homicide).

Thus, there is no conflict between Ex 20:13 and Ex 21:12, 22:19, Lev 20:10.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure which ‘lens’ you are wearing with this observation. Nevertheless, the ‘view’ needs to be kept in the *correct* perspective - so let’s analyse this *perspective*.

The ‘Death Penalty’ verses you quoted, all of them, are *all* related to the Law. There was only one penalty for ‘breaking’ the Law - death. The ‘wages’ of ‘sin’, when judged by the Law, is death (of the flesh).

This is *not* murder. This is what was ‘due’ - if judged! The Israelites had *put themselves* under the Law - and therefore were subject to it.

The incident in John 8 is *exactly* the same scenario. That Lady was being judged under the Law. The ‘judges’ were the Pharisees, acting on behalf of their father. And,note that Jesus *did not argue the judgement*! (He could not, because He was under that same Law).

So what is murder? Murder is when you *unjustifiably* take a man’s life. Where as that penalty of ‘death’ *under* the Law *is* justified! Huge difference!

Comment: But in the ten commandments it states "Thou shall not kill" how can this be possible Dave, I didn't comprehend very well.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo I’m a little surprised that *you* don’t understand? That commandment (Exodus 20:23 - ‘rāṣaḥ’), needs to be understood Hebraically. The clear ‘*intent/meaning*’ implied here is **unlawful** killing.  It all comes down to ‘the Law’ (Torah).

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo Even in your question you quote the command properly: "You shall not murder." Why do you misstate it here?